# How can I find the numebr of TLS and DTLS raw data in pcap?

Tags: ssl, scapy, pcap, tshark, dtls

I want to parse a pcap file and find the number of encrypted data, both TLS and DTLS separately. Scapy doesn't support the DTLS layer, but I understand there is a support package (https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/) that can handle this issue.

```
scapy-ssl_tls
```

The problem is I got problems with importing packages e.g TLS and DTLS Records

```
from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import TLS
```

Can you please suggest any methods to find the number of encrypted data e.g. tshark?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by "number of encrypted data". The number of encrypted bytes contained in (d)tls records?

Comment: I mean the number of packets that have encrypted data (TLS or DTLS)

Comment: for dtls, you may check for the "header" of an dtls record, see https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/wiki/DTLS-1.2-based-firewall for more details, how to detect a valid dtls record.